# Error when using wget to https via proxy

Tags: proxy, https, wget

My browser uses my PC's proxy setting. As far as I can see it uses some $http_URL. So, I put

```
https_proxy=$http_URL
http_proxy=$http_URL
```

The http connection work fine

```
wget $http_URL
```

but I can't get https connection to work. The error I get is

```
Connecting to autocache.xxx.com|x.x.x.x|:80... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Since the proxy setting works on the browser, maybe missing some setting in `wget`?

Some other post mentioned the error is because my connection is not targeting port 443 on the target host. I would have thought

```
wget $https_URL
```

should be going to port 443?

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, with the http_proxy setting if i replaced instead of  the command https://, to
    wget http://some.domain.com:443/path

Then it works fine.